# Error when using line profiling a function that's called by another function

Tags: python, function, time, profiling, profiler

I am using `lprun` to do line profiling for my code in Jupyterlab. The structure of my code and the way I use lprun is as below.

```
def fn1(a,b,c,d):
    ...
    y=fn2(a,c)  #is ok

    # but %lprun -f fn2 y=fn2(a,c) gives error

def fn2(a,c):
    .....
    .....

my_main_code lines
 ....
 %lprun -f fn1 x=fn1(a,b,c,d)
 .....
```

As you see, my main code calls `fn1` and it calls `fn2`. When I use `lprun` just for `fn1` it works well and I saw that `fn2` takes a lot of time. So, I decided to put lprun command on the `fn2` call as shown above as a comment. **But it then throws an error that name `c` is not defined. **So, how can I do line profiling on `fn2`?****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this on my own! To make the profiler display the time statistics for `fn2` also, instead of original `%lprun -f fn1 x=fn1(a,b,c,d)`  **replace with** `%lprun -f fn2 -f fn1 x=fn1(a,b,c,d)`.

If you put `lprun` inside `fn1` while calling `fn2`, it throws the error as in question.